# Local WordPress website administration on two PCs

Tags: wordpress, xampp

I have already installed [XAMPP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XAMPP) in my local computer and also a WordPress website. Is there a way to see the default page of my WordPress website (only the page, not the administration) from an another PC in the same network (home network)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Having a URL such as `http://example.dev/index.php` instead of `http://localhost/example/index.php` is much clearer, works better with some website "extensions" involving paths and routing, and stored passwords are much easier to manage in browsers. Let's face it; it's just better all around.

Since you've asked for external access (two PCs), I've changed this from my original configuration example, which is isolated from access except through the loopback interface. This example assumes your LAN is properly secured. Either firewall your LAN or change configuration as noted in commented portions of the configuration file to be more specific about access.

There are a few steps to get it working, but once you get used to the two files you'll work with, it's quite easy to set up a new project later.

#### Activate Modules in *httpd.conf*

```
LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so
LoadModule log_config_module modules/mod_log_config.so
```

#### Activate Virtual Host Settings in *httpd.conf*

```
#Listen 12.34.56.78:80
Listen 80

<VirtualHost *:80>
```

Comment out directory information

```
#DocumentRoot "E:/xampp/htdocs"
#<Directory "E:/xampp/htdocs">
...
```

Be sure to close the *VirtualHost* directive before the file includes:

```
</VirtualHost>
```

#### Configure Virtual Hosts Configuration File

After making the previous changes to Apache’s base-level configuration file, you can work with the vhost extra configuration file (`%xampp%/apache/conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf`).

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@myexamplesite.dev
    DocumentRoot "C:\Users\JHaas\Documents\Projects\MyExampleSite"
    ServerName myexamplesite.dev
    ServerAlias myexamplesite.dev
    ErrorLog "logs/myexamplesite.dev-error.log"
    CustomLog "logs/myexamplesite.dev-access.log" common

    <Directory "C:\Users\JHaas\Documents\Projects\MyExampleSite">
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride all
        Order Deny,Allow
        Deny from none
        Allow from all
        #Allows a specific IP to access your VHost
        #Allow from 10.0.0.24
    </Directory>

    DirectoryIndex index.html index.php
</VirtualHost>
```

#### Editing /etc/hosts

Finally, you edit the [/etc/hosts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hosts_(file)) file. This file helps your system bypass the need for a [DNS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_Name_System) query, allowing you to create your own [TLD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Top-level_domain) (top-level domain) suffix, such as `*.dev`, or anything that isn’t going to collide with current new top-level domain suffixes (`*.me` used to be quite popular until that suffix itself became a TLD suffix).

The `localhost` entry is not always required (depending on platform), and from my experience has actually caused problems if uncommented, so leave it commented out if it is already. If you see that localhost is not commented out (again, depending on your platform), be sure to leave it so. Changing the localhost entry from default can cause issues for many network services if it’s changed.

Also note that Google Chrome *has an issue* with using `*.local`, so it’s probably best to avoid using this TLD suffix.

Host computer:

```
127.0.0.1   localhost
127.0.0.1   myexamplesite.dev
```

On the other computer, modify the `/etc/hosts` file to have an entry for your computer.

```
10.0.0.27   myexamplesite.dev
```

You can test your changes to the configuration files via command line using `apache/bin/httpd.exe -t`. This runs a syntax check on your configuration files.

Answer (score 0):

Let’s assume the IP address of the PC running XAMPP is *192.168.0.198* and you are using the standard XAMPP setting regarding ports and the WordPress sites folder (*testproject*) sits in the XAMPP *htdocs* folder, then you could access the site within the local network via:

```
http://192.168.0.198:8888/testproject/
```

Comment: Could this be a solution to developing on devices? (WAMP)?

Comment: I use localhost. It is possible to set up through XAMPP a "site.dev" url protocol. I'll have my colleague answer this as he's just finished a write-up on the matter.